# Autoplay embedded videos using Facebook's graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm embedding a facebook video on a page using:

```
<iframe style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" frameborder="0" marginheight="0"
 marginwidth="0" allowfullscreen="true" title="Facebook video player"
 src="https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=' + videoID + '"></iframe>
```

Is there a way to make the video auto-play, start muted, etc? Other embeddable video players do this by accepting url params. However, I could find no such thing in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/video).

**p.s.** I am aware that FB videos can also be embedded using their JS SDK (which does support autoplay), but I am looking for a way to do it using the above method.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook policy does not allow autoplay of embedded content.
You could try to fiddle a way around with some nasty jQuery stuff to fake the click on the play button but this wont last for long, due to frequently code changes. Either use the JS SDK or use a platform like Youtube.